# Como passar os dados de um input para javascript e depois apresenta-lo

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho este código para ir buscar o valor da minha input

```
<Script>

 var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para apresenta-lo num spam por exemplo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo simples utilizando apenas javascript.

```js
var mostrarNome = function (){
  var exibicao = document.getElementById("exibir");
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  
  exibicao.innerText = nome;  
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nome" />
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="mostrarNome()">Exibir</button>
<br />
<span id="exibir"></span>
```